# Search in nested Postgresql JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

How to search in nested jsonb column in Rails.

```
Model: Shop
jsonb column: shop_data

shop_data: {
  common_data: {
    "image_url" => "https://sample.com/img.jpg"
    "token" => "AOsa2123ASDasdaasasda"
    "uid" => ""
    "expires_at" => ""
  }
}
```

Wanna make a scopes that will checks for records where:

```
1. shop_data->common_data->expires_at IS NOT NULL
2. shop_data->common_data->image_url IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
 1. scope :expired, -> { where("shop_data -> 'common_data' ->> 'expires_at' IS NOT NULL") }
 2. scope :null_image, -> { where("shop_data -> 'common_data' ->> 'image_url' IS NULL") }
```

source [JSON functions in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html)

Hope it helps