# How to query nested JSONB format data column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have data gene expression data in jsosnb column in multiple rows for different samples as shown below:

```
Sample       Gexp
Sample A    {"data": [{"pval": 0.0154, "Protein": "A0A0B4J2D5", "FoldChange": 1.3534, "MinusLog10p": 0.1334, "Significance": "Non-significant"}, {"pval": 0.0689, "Protein": "A0FGR8", "FoldChange": 2.5448, "MinusLog10p": 1.1615, "Significance": "Significant"}]}
Sample B    {"data": [{"pval": 0.0824, "Protein": "A0A0B4J2D5", "FoldChange": -0.1676, "MinusLog10p": 0.1084, "Significance": "Non-significant"}, {"pval": 0.0219, "Protein": "A0FGR8", "FoldChange": 2.3448, "MinusLog10p": 1.1615, "Significance": "Significant"}]}
```

I need to query across the column containing multiple records where a certain protein has a pval or FoldChange in a certain range. I tried multiple solutions provided in this forum ([Search in nested Postgresql JSONB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315340/search-in-nested-postgresql-jsonb-column), [Postgresql query for objects in nested JSONB field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130740/postgresql-query-for-objects-in-nested-jsonb-field), [Query simplified JSONB form JSONB column containing nested JSON from a Postgresql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079009/query-simplified-jsonb-form-jsonb-column-containing-nested-json-from-a-postgresq), [How to query nested array with heterogeneous elements in PostgreSQL JSONB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986448/how-to-query-nested-array-with-heterogeneous-elements-in-postgresql-jsonb-column), etc., with no luck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions for selecting the data were not precisely (unambiguously) described in the question. Exemplary, when we are looking for the `A0FGR8` protein in the `pval` range of `0.02` to `0.03`, the query might look like this:

```sql
select sample, value
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(gexp->'data')
where value->>'Protein' = 'A0FGR8'
and (value->>'pval')::numeric between 0.02 and 0.03
```

Test the query in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/hEfUhZbv)